# Android wallpaper apps that update images every week

Tags: android, wallpaper

I see some wallpaper apps on the market and they update the images daily or weekly. I wonder how they do that. I use picasso library but I cannot do that with picasso. Is there anyone can help?

Comment: Dupicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892909/how-can-i-set-wallpaper-in-android-using-coding

Answer (score -1):

One way to achieve what you want is you can make webservice/api to pass image url from the server and now anytime whatever image url that api will respond/contains that you can load in your ImageView. And that't it.

**Note - You must have a knowledge of making webservice and calling them and handling the http request response in advance for this before applying this approach.**

Thanks.